# Report Desinging acuamtica

Tags: c#, sql, acumatica

Can I use the SQL query in Acumatica's report [value tab]?

eg I want my rounding adjustment to always appear as the last item in the list the query, I would use as such:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CustomerID = 12 THEN NULL ELSE CustomerID END
```

But that seems not to work on the report designer.

Answer (score 3):

The report schema builder wizard generates SQL but you can't include direct SQL in Acumatica Report Designer.

For your use case, you would have to create a custom field in `Customer` table for sorting.

In the report designer schema builder `Sorting and Grouping` tab you can sort the `Customer` using that custom field.

Report `SO641000` uses that approach to sort the `SOLine` transactions with a custom sort order.

[image]